# Add data labels to the last point in a series in excel

Tags: excel, charts, format, vba

I have around 50 charts in an excel worksheet which I should update every month. 
I need a VBA code which would add data labels to the last point in the data series, to all the charts in the worksheet.
My each Chart has 3 series, but I need to add labels for that month's data(latest point) to ONLY ONE series which would be YTD amount.
I have no knowledge in writing VBA code. I have seen couple codes and tried copying and making small changes, but no code suits my requirement. I don't want to make 50+ changes every month manually, so any thing that would address my issue would be very helpful. I greatly appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this ought to get you started:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub AddLabelsLastPoint()

    Dim ch As ChartObject

    'Loop through each chart object
    For Each ch In Worksheets("Sheet3").ChartObjects

        'Grab the final series of the chart
        With ch.Chart.SeriesCollection(3)
            'Apply data label to final point in series
            .Points(.Points.Count).ApplyDataLabels
        End With

    Next ch


End Sub
```

Open the VB Editor with <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> (or go to Developer --> Visual Basic on the ribbon) and then right click the 'Microsoft Excel Objects' --> Insert --> Module

Be sure to change `Worksheets("Sheet3")` to whichever worksheet you are using.  Additionally, this code assumes that your YTD amount will always be the last series, hence the `SeriesCollection(3)` of each chart.  If this isn't the case, we will need to modify the code, but this is a starting point at least.

Since you say you have no knowledge of writing VBA, I will point out two other things (which are irrelevant to your problem, but good to know nonetheless).

First is the `Option Explicit` keyboard.  This forces variables to be declared before they can be used.  It is good practice to include this in your VBA code.  If you don't include this, you may get unexpected results (if, for example, you misspell a variable name).

Second is the `Private` keyword.  This means that only code within the current module can access the subroutine.

Comment: Thank you Josh! I was able to execute the code except for that, like you mentioned the series that I would like to label is the 2nd one and not the last. So, I kind of have an issue here. I changed the seriescollection to (2) but I don't think it would make any difference though.

Comment: Changing the `.SeriesCollection(3)` to `.SeriesCollection(2)` should do the 2nd series of each chart.  If it doesn't, I will need to think of another way to find the proper series.

Comment: It doesn't, basically my series is a clustered column which is overlayed,  that is causing an issue I believe. I changed the code to different series numbers I have, so every other series is labeled except for the one I want. So, I think I will record a macro at this point and run it every month. Thank you for your help!